# Modificar valor que cambia otro valor en SQL

Tags: sql, pdo

Mi función Update:

```
    public function Update($pcosto, $user_id)

{
    $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET pcosto = :pcosto WHERE id = :id");
    $query->bindParam("pcosto", $pcosto, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam("id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
}
```

Tengo una función Update que recibe un precio de costo (pcosto) y el id del producto para modificarlo. Lo que quisiera hacer en la sentencia sql es que:
Se actualice el precio de costo(que ya lo hace) y además que modifique el valor
**dif** realizando dif: pventa - pcosto(el valor que recibe el Update). Espero que se entienda.

Algunas consideraciones para entender mejor:

- La DB tiene id, pventa(precio de venta), pcosto ( precio costo), y dif (diferencia de pventa-pcosto).
- Modificar principalmente el pcosto, pero con la modificación de este que también realice la modificación de **dif** restando **pventa** al valor actualizado de **pcosto**. Al actualizar el pcosto se actualice  dif automáticamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mira debes de realizar otra consulta despues de realizar el cambio para que asi tomes en comun el id que vas a operar.

```
public function Update($pcosto, $user_id){
    $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET pcosto = :pcosto WHERE id = :id");
    $query->bindParam("pcosto", $pcosto, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam("id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();

//Actualizo el costo

    $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET dif = (pventa-pcosto) WHERE id = :id"); 
    $query->bindParam("id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
    $query->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el parámetro es más de un lugar al mismo tiempo en tu consulta

```
public function Update($pcosto, $user_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET pcosto = :pcosto, dif = pventa - :pcosto WHERE id = :id");
    $query->bindParam("pcosto", $pcosto, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam("id", $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
}
```

Espero la respuesta haya sido útil.